# How to add auto complete to classes instantiated with custom function?

Tags: php, oop, autocomplete, static-analysis

I instantiate my classes through custom functions.

The classes are in **app/code/core/** e.g.

**app/code/core/Property/Helper/Property.php**

```
require_once("Core/Helper.php");

class Property_Helper_Property extends Core\Helper
{
    public function __construct($con)
    {
        parent::__construct($con);
    }

    public function test()
    {
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

**app/code/core/Core/Helper.php**

```
<?php
namespace Core;

abstract class Helper
{
    protected $con;

    public function __construct($con)
    {
        $this->con = $con;
    }
}
```

I can call the method `test()` of the class `Property_Helper_Property` from any file like this:

```
require_once 'app/Main.php';  // always needed

Main::getHelper("Property/Property")->test();
```

**app/Main.php**

This file contains the final class "Main" which has the static method getHelper

```
if (!defined('DS')) define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
if (!defined('PS')) define('PS', PATH_SEPARATOR);
if (!defined('BP')) define('BP', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

/**
 * Set include path
 */
    Main::register('original_include_path', get_include_path());

    $paths = array();
    $paths[] = Main::CORE_PATH;
    $paths[] = Main::LOCAL_PATH;
    $paths[] = BP . DS . 'lib';
    $paths[] = BP . DS . 'inc';

    $appPath = implode(PS, $paths);
    set_include_path($appPath . PS . Main::registry('original_include_path'));

final class Main
{
    const CORE_PATH = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'core';
    const LOCAL_PATH = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'local';

    /**
     * Registry collection
     *
     * @var array
     */
    static private $_registry = array();

    public static function getDbConnection()
    {
        return self::registry("db_connection");
    }

    /**
     * Register a new variable
     *
     * @param string $key
     * @param mixed $value
     * @param bool $graceful
     */
    public static function register($key, $value, $graceful = false)
    {
        if (isset(self::$_registry[$key])) {
            if ($graceful) {
                return;
            }
            self::throwException('Main registry key "'.$key.'" already exists');
        }
        self::$_registry[$key] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Unregister a variable from register by key
     *
     * @param string $key
     */
    public static function unregister($key)
    {
        if (isset(self::$_registry[$key])) {
            if (is_object(self::$_registry[$key]) && (method_exists(self::$_registry[$key], '__destruct'))) {
                self::$_registry[$key]->__destruct();
            }
            unset(self::$_registry[$key]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a value from registry by a key
     *
     * @param string $key
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function registry($key)
    {
        if (isset(self::$_registry[$key])) {
            return self::$_registry[$key];
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static function getHelper($name)
    {
        $classPath = self::getClassPath($name, "Helper");
        if (!$classPath) { return false; }

        $fullClassPath = self::getFullClassPath($classPath);
        if (!$fullClassPath) { return false; }

        $obj = self::getClassInstance($fullClassPath, $classPath);
        if (!$obj) { return false; }

        return $obj;
    }

    public static function getModel($name)
    {
        $classPath = self::getClassPath($name, "Model");
        if (!$classPath) { return false; }

        $fullClassPath = self::getFullClassPath($classPath);
        if (!$fullClassPath) { return false; }

        $obj = self::getClassInstance($fullClassPath, $classPath);
        if (!$obj) { return false; }

        return $obj;
    }

    private function getClassInstance($fullClassPath, $classPath)
    {
        if (!$classPath) { return false; }

        require_once($fullClassPath);

        $className = str_replace("/", "_", $classPath);

        if (class_exists($className)) {
            return new $className(self::getDbConnection());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function getFullClassPath($classPath)
    {
        $modulPaths = [self::CORE_PATH, self::LOCAL_PATH];
        return self::checkIfFileExistInModule($modulPaths, $classPath);
    }

    private function getClassPath($modelName, $identifier="Model")
    {
        if (strpos($modelName, '/') === false) { return false; }

        if (substr_count($modelName, "/") == 1) {
            $exp = explode("/", $modelName);
            return $exp[0] . "/$identifier/" . $exp[1];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function checkIfFileExistInModule($modulPaths, $modelname)
    {
        foreach($modulPaths as $path) {
            $path = $path . DS . $modelname . ".php";
            if (file_exists($path)) {
                return $path;
            }
        }

        return "0";
    }

}
```

This works just fine... now the actual question.

If I am writing...

```
$obj = Main::getHelper("Property/Property");
$obj->
```

...then my IDE (NetBeans) does not auto suggest the public methods/properties which I can use.

Is there a way to "teach" my logic to add auto suggestion / auto completion so that it automatically shows all public methods/properties available in the object?

Comment: You need to use `IDE` like `php storm` it is smart enough to suggest

Comment: I am using Netbeans.

Comment: try `PHP STorm` it is awesome in autocomplete but for advice don't use autocomplete as much as you can

Comment: @Joseph That's some bad advice, give me a reason why I wouldn't use autocomplete?

Comment: @Daan for me i still a beginner so i don't like to use auto-complete much to learn to write it fast then when i learn it well i will use autocomplete

Comment: Any reason for the rollback? All the included code I removed is really not relevant to the question, and makes it much harder to read.

Comment: Plus adding the tag in the title is not good, and a bit of grammar here and there, adding back irrelevant tags... you really undid quite a bit of work. Any reason for that?

Comment: @yivi, You removed the whole code where I show the logic behind `getHelper`. I need people to see it so they understand what I am doing and point it out if there is anything to improve. Without this code, they can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not really, the factory method is well understood. If anything, you need to show **only** `getHelper`, not anything else. Do you mind if edit it again, leaving only that part? I really like that the questions I answer are as good as possible.

Comment: No, all the code is needed to be able to reproduce the problem. So please leave it as it is...

Comment: No, the code is **not** necessary to reproduce the problem. I didn't even read it to answer the question. I had to ignore it because it actually distracts from your problem. I will at least fix title and tags, that are simply wrong.

Comment: If you can reproduce it without recreating the project with the code, then it is also fine. But not everyone is this skilled. I will leave it there for educational purposes and for improvement suggestions. You can edit the tags

Comment: I can answer it without the code because **the code is not relevant to the problem**. This is not a debugging question, so only minimal code is needed. The code only makes the question much harder to read, since it makes unclear where the problem resides. The only arguably needed bit is the definition of `Main::getHelper()`.

Comment: And all the functions you can see in the Main class are relevant for the definition of `Main::getHelper()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [phpdoc blocks](https://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/index.html). Pretty sure they are supported by NetBeans:

```
/** @var Property_Helper_Property $obj */
$obj = Main::getHelper("Property/Property");
```

From that point forward auto-completion and static analysis will work, since it will be understood that `$obj` will be an instance of `Property_Helper_Property`.

Comment: I added `/** @var Property_Helper_Property $obj */` before `$obj = Main::getHelper("Property/Property");` and it does not work.

Comment: Is `Property_Helper_Property` inside a namespace? Or the file where you are using this annotation? In any case, either use an import or a fully qualified class name. E.g. if it's on root `\Property_Helper_Property`. I do not have netbeans installed right now (spend some bucks and get PhpStorm), but I'm told this works on NB as well.

Comment: What version of netbeans are you on?

Comment: The code is 1:1 the same here on SO and on my project, so as you can see it is not in a namespace. I am using 8.2, because the latest NetBeans has a major bug which makes xdebug fail.

Comment: Try using `/* @var foo $bar */`. I think older versions of NetBeans didn't follow the PhpDocumentor standard correctly.

Comment: Does not work either. I just tested the first version which you have mentioned in the latest Netbeans, and there it works. But is there a better way or do I really have to write this doc block every single time I use a helper or model ?

Comment: It's either that or creating methods with declared return types. You could create wrappers for your factory method. E.g. `getPropertyHelper(): Property_Helper_Property {}`, wrapping your factory method. It's not possible to infer what the method would return otherwise.